# Replacing -inf with the minimum value of the same dataframe

Tags: r

I want to replace "-inf" with the minimum value of the same column.As R consider "-inf" as minimum value. I was unable to replace with the minimum number.

Any idea? I tried something like this

```
      b[,12][(b[,12]== -Inf)] <- min(b[,12])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to subset the `b[,12]` without the `-Inf` and then take the `min`

```
b[,12][(b[,12]== -Inf)] <- min(b[,12][b[,12] != -Inf])
```

Comment: We can also use the `is.finite` function, e.g. `x[x == -Inf] <- min(x[is.finite(x)])`.